# How I can prove tht $T$ is isomorphic to a finite set of natural numbers?

Tags: finite-groups

Let $T$ be a finite abelian group. We can consider $T$ the as group $ℤ/nℤ$ or $ℤ/qℤ×ℤ/mℤ$.

**My question** is: How I can prove tht $T$ is in bijection with a finite set of natural numbers?

That is, I want to prove that there is a bijection between $T$ and a finite set of natural numbers ${1,2,...,q}$ where $q$ is the finite size of $T$.

Comment: What is the group structure on a finite set of natural numbers?

Comment: The standard summations of natural numbers.

Comment: But it would not be closed under addition.

Comment: @Chaos Are you sure you mean standard summation? Don't you mean sum modulus some natural number?

Comment: I have changed isomorphism to bijection. Sorry.

Comment: @Chaos What's your definition of finite set?

Comment: A set with a finite number of elements.

Comment: @Chaos Given the question as it is, I don't understand what that means, to be honest.

Comment: Wikipedia for one defines finite to mean bijection with a finite set of natural numbers...

Comment: I want to prove that there is a bijection between $T$ and a finite set of natural numbers ${1,2,...,q}$ where $q$ is the finite size of $T$.

Comment: @Abel: Yes. This is the definition.

Comment: Where $T$ is a finite abelian group or where $T$ is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ say?

Comment: @Chaos The problem here is the definition of *finite set*.As Abel pointed out, one possible definition of a set $X$ to be called finite, is that there exists a bijection between $X$ and $[n\textbf{]}$, for some $n\in \Bbb N_0$, where $[n\textbf{]}=\{0,1,\ldots ,n-1 \}$. And if this is your definition, then there's nothing left to prove.

Comment: @GitGud. Yes this is my definition. To Abel: In all cases the groups have finite number of elements.

Comment: @Babak S: But I need the expression of that bijection.

Comment: @Chaos As I have pointed out, there is nothing left to prove. What you want to prove is the definition of finite set.

Comment: @Chaos That should have been pointed out eariler. Please add that information to the question's body.

Comment: @Chaos `To Abel: In all cases the groups have finite number of elements.' By definition or is this what you want to prove?

Comment: If $T$ is finite, you can mark its elements by natural numbers as $x_0,x_1,...,x_{|T|}$.

Comment: @Babak S, Abel and Git Gud: Ok I understand the idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Abel: Thank you very much for you answer. Then How about the case of $ℤ/qℤ×ℤ/mℤ$ I still confused about it.

Comment: By my argument you have a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and $\{1,\ldots,q\}\times\{1,\ldots,m\} = \{(i,j)|1\leq i\leq q\mbox{ and }1\leq j\leq m\}$. It is pretty straight forward to find a bijection from this set to the set $\{1,\ldots,q\cdot m\}$, define for instance $\psi((i,j)) = (i-1)\cdot m +j$.

Comment: @Abel: Thank you very much for your valauable comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too long to be a comment, so I hope it answers your question:

Lets consider $\mathbb{Z}_n = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. We want to construct a bijection with the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Any $a\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ that is closed under addition with multiples of $n$. Since it is closed under addition with arbitrarily large numbers, it must contain some positive number. Define $\phi(a)$ to be the smallest positive number contained in $a$.

Suppose $\phi(a)>n$, then $\phi(a)-n$ is positive and smaller than $\phi(a)$, a contradiction. Thus $\phi\colon \mathbb{Z}_n\to\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Now it remains to show that $\phi$ is a bijection. Clearly $\phi$ is surjective, since $\phi(\{mn+k|m\in\mathbb{Z}\})=k$ for any $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
Furthermore $\phi$ in injective, since $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$ implies that $\phi(a)\in a\cap b$ and the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ partition $\mathbb{Z}$.